# Google+:Get friends list (HTTP 403 forbidden)

Tags: ios, cordova, google-plus

I am working with ['Google+ Sign-In'](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) in an iOS PhoneGap application. I am getting user profile details except friends list. I tried this

`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?key={apikey}`

but I am getting following error:

```
{
 "error": {`enter code here`
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

How can i fix this problem??Please suggest a solution.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using a simple API key. You need to first authorize the user against the Google+ APIs using Google+ Sign-In as described in the [iOS documentation for Google+](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/).

If you are signing in the user and are getting an access token, you should pass the access token as opposed to your simple API key instead when [calling the API using the credentials you have received after the user authorizes your app](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#callinganapi).